# How to clear the app from the recent app list

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-instant-apps

We are developing an app to help domestic violence victims. The goal of the app is to let the victim hop into a quick chat with the entities responsible to protect those victims.

However, there is a gimmick. The app, should not let any trail of it after the victim has closed the app. This is to avoid making the situation uglier between the abuser and the victim, in case the abuser gets the victim's phone.

Now, I have been testing instant apps for this, and it seems really promising. The app runs, but on closing it, there is no app in the drawer. But digging a bit further, getting to the phone settings and checking the app list, I can see that the app is there. If I click the app (from the apps list), and "Clear app", then the app is removed. But that is not ideal for victims.

I have tried to [clearApplicationUserData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#clearApplicationUserData()) on the activity destroy method, but no joy.

Is there any way to avoid this? Also, I am open to other approaches that would suit this project better.

Comment: "The app, should not let any trail of it after the victim has closed the app" -- then IMHO this should be a Web app accessed through a browser's incognito mode, rather than be a native Android app (instant or otherwise).